# Three-phase full-wave bridge converter maximum firing delay

Tags: rectifier, full-bridge, hvdc, commutation

According to the textbook *Power System Stability and Control* by Prabha Kundur, the maximum firing delay of a thyristor is 180° with the following explanation:

[image]

[image]

Why is he considering eb with ea? Doesn’t ec become greater than eb at 120° making the maximum firing delay 120°?

Comment: Valve 3 can be fired (alpha = 0°) if eb (voltage at anode) is greater than the other two (ea and ec, voltages at cathode of valve 3, valve 5 is also delayed, so until 180°). If I remember well, at this point, there is very little positive voltage, so usually, delay is limited to 150°.

Comment: If not, next firing could be problematic for the other valves ... and when a valve can't be switched OFF, because of the fact that the load is inductive (current has same sense, the valve is always ON), there can be a loss of control, and valve "can" continue to be ON for a whole period (until the next firing). This is a "short" in fact, and there will be an overcurrent that the valve must withstand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See reference at this [link](https://www.plexim.com/academy/power-electronics/thyristor-rect-ind-load) and this [one](https://moodle-app2.let.ethz.ch/course/view.php?id=17722&lang=en).

This circuit is called a **full SCR PD3 made with all SCR in all branches**.
You have noted that the **load inductor is infinite**, which "says" that the **current into the load is "constant"**.
The same thing can thus be made in simulation with a current source.
The behavior says also that for some angles the output **voltage** is **positive** (**current is positive** into the load) and for some other angles, the output **voltage** is **negative** (**current always positive!**).
This is called a "**non-autonomous**" converter.

You can also see the phenomena of **SCR "overlap"**.
In this case, **two SCR are shorting their own phases** (same side), and "overlap" occurs. (because of the inductors **L2-L3-L4** of the generators).
One SCR (switching OFF) passes the current to a new SCR (switching ON).

See also the **shift of the current** into L2-L3-L4 or the voltage generators.

Here is the schematic used. A bit complicated by the "delays" ...
The **black line is the output voltage** for some alpha angles or delays of firing.

[image]

Firing Angle ~ 0°, -> maximum positive output voltage.
[image]

Currents ...
[image]

Firing Angle ~ 90°, -> average output voltage = 0.
[image]

Currents ...
[image]

Firing Angle ~ 150°, -> quasi maximum negative output voltage.
[image]

Currents ...
[image]

Firing Angle ~ 160°, -> maximum negative output voltage.
[image]

Firing Angle > 160°, -> loss of control, do you see what is happening?
Time to "stop" current **within one cycle**.
[image]